# how to Scroll down in a html table using arrowkeys?

Tags: javascript, html, scrollbar

I'm developing a web application and encountered following problem.

there are two tables in my page and when i select a row in table1 , first row in table2  get selected.I want to scroll down the table2 using arrow keys(without click in any row of table2). But when I use arrow keys, scroll bar doesn't work. It work only after I click a row in table2.

Is there any javascript solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

You may need to set the focus:

```
tables2.tabIndex = 1; // allows focus   
table2.focus();
```

Comment: I couldn't set focus in the table. But when I put a <a> tag and set focus to it, scrollbar works.

Comment: My bad. The table needs to have a tabIndex.
table2.tabIndex = 1;

Answer (score 0):

You may get pressed keys and scroll from javascript. Scrolling solution for jQuery:

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 300}, 500);
```

will scroll to 300px from top by 500ms